# Keras SparseCategoricalCrossentropy flatten the input label

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm training an image multi-classifier.
Using the loss SparseCategoricalCrossentropy in Keras.
I found a problem below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.constant([[0.,0.,1.],[1.,0.,0.]])
b=tf.constant([[0.,0.,1.],[0.,1.,0.]])
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss = loss_object(a, b)
```

a represents true label for my 2 input data.
b represents prediction label for my 2 input data.
The computation meet an error below.

```
ValueError: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(6,) and logits.shape=(2, 3)
```

It's somehow that the true labels are flatten and become uncomputable.
How can I deal with this problem to compute SparseCategoricalCrossentropy with respect to 2 input data?

Answer (score 0):

Your labels are not sparse, they are one-hot encoded, meaning the `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` won't work. To fix that, change

```
a=tf.constant([[0.,0.,1.],[1.,0.,0.]])
```

to

```
a=tf.constant([2., 0.])
```

This will work because a is the first parameter for the call of the loss function, which is the ground truth, or `y_true`:

```
loss = loss_object(a, b)
```

It's okay for `b` to be one-hot encoded, as TensorFlow will convert it to the right format, but this only seems to work if `a` is in the right (sparse) format already.